# Store PDF to Google Drive

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Does anybody know how to do a Script tha create a PDF from a Google Doc and store it into Google Drive?, this was my function

```
  var Folder = DocsList.getFolder(FOLDER);


  var doc = DocsList.getFileById(DOC_ID);
 var docName = doc.getName();
  var pdf = doc.getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();

 //This suppose to be the accion, but such function cant be found 
 pdf.addToFolder(Folder);
```

Comment: What errors did you receive? What isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var pdf = doc.getAs('application/pdf');
Folder.createFile(pdf);
```

To keep things simple, you want to keep your file contents as a Blob. (i.e. don't call `getBytes()`. Then create a file using the Blob. `Folder.createFile(...)` is the function that you were looking for.